# Is it possible to run a spring annotation based unit test with jmeter?

Tags: spring, junit, jmeter

```
@ContextConfiguration
(
  {

   "file:Spring-Test.xml"

  }
)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AppTest 
{
    @Autowired
    World world;

 //Test method
}
```

The test runs fine in eclipse but when the `jar` of the `test class` is put under `jmeter` it does not recognize the annotations. Loading the spring context through `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` works.Please help